# Why hibernate can not find my view

Tags: mysql, xml, hibernate, view

I created a database view in mysql named like 'some_thing', and then use the hibernate auto generating tools to generate a xml file like this

```
<class name="SomeThing" table="some_thing">
```

However, when I try to operate the view there is an error says

```
[ERROR]Table 'something' doesn't exist -- org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter.logExceptions
```

as you see, hibernate didn't use the name I appointed in the xml file, and if I follow the tips and change the name of the view to something the error change into

```
[ERROR]Table 'some_thing' doesn't exist -- org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter.logExceptions
```

so I tried change the xml to 'something' and also change the name of the view to 'something' the error is

```
[ERROR]Table 'some_thing' doesn't exist -- org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter.logExceptions
```

Please tell me why can this happened, thanks.

my environment is hibernate 3.3, mysql 5.5, navicat 9.0, myeclipse 8.6

Comment: looks like there are multiple copies of the Something.hbm.xml floating around. old jar, multiple hbms something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to improve your self `"<class name="SomeThing" table="some_thing"/>"` you have not closed tags !! Try to use debug option ! If it doesnt allow to debug in xml file , try to find another way of finding solution !

Have you analyzed definition of `class` tag ?