# Call Database views using Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I m doing project in Spring MVC with Hibernate, i m using MySQL DB. In my Database i m having an View already created, i want to call that view using hibernate.

so i refered [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875368/why-hibernate-can-not-find-my-view) here in answer you will see `"<class name="SomeThing" table="some_thing"/>"` so,

Class name `Something` is an java class which have properties which are columns in database view right?

And what about other part of mapping do i need to add `<property>` in mapping?

Comment: Yes. you should have <property> tags to map columns of the view to your bean. However note that mapping a java bean to a view (like doing it for a table) will work fine for read operations. However there will be complications when trying to delete/update, or it will most likely be impossible in most scenarios.

Comment: If you start with Hibernate, then forget about XML-based mapping. Use annotations instead : more standard, clearer, easier.

Comment: @DevBlanked Thank You for your reply :).most of my views are for read operations so nothing to worry.if i make mapping for this so i have add `<mapping resource>` in `hibernate.cfg.xml` right? if i add entry for mapping file in `hibernate.cfg.xml` then it will make table, isn't it? OR no need to add entry in hibernate file just use criteria API,HQL to get data from database view.

Comment: @Amogh most probably you will need to create the view manually. I doubt whether hibernate can know it's mapped to a view since the mapping doesn't say anything like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the View class same as other entity classes. You can use annotation, property, mappping and other relations as well. In my project we have used the same but db is PostgreSQL. That is does not matter.

Comment: Hey Amough, when you accept any answer, you supposed to give some upvote for that answer for appreciation.